# Templated control in ektron

Tags: ektron

I have tried to retrieve the taxonomy list using taxonomy tree, in edit i am selecting the taxonomy and getting TaxonomyID,by using the taxonomyID i want to display the data using taxonomy filters using templated control.I am unable to retrive the data.I am attaching HTML and Code what i have done,So please help me out for the solution.

```
    <asp:View ID="View" runat="server">          

    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label>            
    <CMS:Directory CssClass="taxList" ID="TaxonomySummary1" EnableAjax="true" runat="server"
                EnablePaging="false"  />

          <ektron:ContentModelSource ID="cntModelSourcs" runat="server" OrderByField="DateCreated" 
    OrderByDirection="Descending">    


   <TaxonomyFilters>
        <ektron:ContentTaxonomyFilter Operator="Contains"  ID="taxFilter" runat="server" />

    </TaxonomyFilters>

     <ContentFilters>   
       <ektron:ContentFilter Field="Id" Operator="EqualTo" Value=""   />
    </ContentFilters>
</ektron:ContentModelSource>

<ektron:ContentView ID="ContentView1" runat="server"  ModelSourceID="cntModelSourcs"  
    EktronCustomTemplate="Ektron_ContentList_Template" >

</ektron:ContentView>
    </asp:View>
```

`enter code here`
      _edit" class="TSWidget">

```
    <div class="ByTaxonomy TSTabPanel">
                    <div style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
                        <UC:TaxonomyTree ID="TaxonomyTree1" runat="server" />

                    </div>
                    <hr />

                </div>
    <div class="ByProperty TSTabPanel">
                    <table style="width: auto;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">
                                <%=m_refMsg.GetMessage("lbl taxonomy id:")%>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="taxonomyid" CssClass="folderid" runat="server" Style="width: auto;"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">
                                <%=m_refMsg.GetMessage("lbl taxonomy path:")%>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="taxonomypath" CssClass="taxonomypath" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                              </td> 
                        </tr>                           
                    </table>
                </div>
    <div class="TSEditControls">
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" CssClass="TSCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="CancelButton_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" CssClass="TSSave" runat="server" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" Text="Save" />                       
                </div>
  </div>

</asp:View>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Ektron.Cms;
using Ektron.Cms.Widget;
using Ektron.Cms.Common;
using Ektron.Cms.API;
using Ektron.Cms.Organization;
using Ektron.Cms.Framework.Organization;
using System.Text;
using Ektron.Cms.Search.Expressions;
using Ektron.Cms.Search;
using Ektron.Cms.Framework;
public partial class widgets_Content_TaxonomyFilter : System.Web.UI.UserControl,IWidget
{
# region Properties
protected string appPath = "";
private Ektron.Cms.CommonApi _commonAPI = new CommonApi();
private long _taxonomyid;
public string TaxonomySelected = "selected";
public string PropertySelected = "selected";
public string m_strTaxonomyPath = "/";
private string _taxonomypath;

[WidgetDataMember(0)]
public long TaxonomyId { get { return _taxonomyid; } set { _taxonomyid = value; } }

[WidgetDataMember("")]
public string TaxonomyPaths { get { return _taxonomypath; } set { 
_taxonomypath         =       value; } }    private IWidgetHost _host;    
protected ContentAPI m_refContentApi = new ContentAPI();
protected EkMessageHelper m_refMsg;
#endregion

# region Page Load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    taxFilter.Value = TaxonomyId.ToString();
    ContentView1.DataBind();
}
#endregion

#region Page Init
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_refMsg = m_refContentApi.EkMsgRef;
    CancelButton.Text = m_refMsg.GetMessage("btn cancel");
    SaveButton.Text = m_refMsg.GetMessage("btn save");
    _host = Ektron.Cms.Widget.WidgetHost.GetHost(this);
    _host.Title = "Templated Control";
    _host.Edit += new EditDelegate(EditEvent);
    _host.Maximize += new MaximizeDelegate(delegate() { Visible = true; });
    _host.Minimize += new MinimizeDelegate(delegate() { Visible = false; });
    _host.Create += new CreateDelegate(delegate() { EditEvent(""); });
    _host.ExpandOptions = Expandable.ExpandOnEdit;
    appPath = _commonAPI.AppPath;
    Load += new EventHandler(delegate(object PreRenderSender, EventArgs Evt) { if 
    (ViewSet.GetActiveView() != Edit) SetTaxonomySummary(); });
    ViewSet.SetActiveView(View);
    }

protected void SetTaxonomySummary()
{
    if (TaxonomyId > 0)
    {
        lblID.Text = Convert.ToString(taxFilter.Value);

    }

}
#endregion

#region EditEvent
void EditEvent(string settings)
{
    try
    {
        string sitepath = _commonAPI.SitePath;
        string webserviceURL = sitepath + "widgets/taxonomysummary/TSHandler.ashx";
        JS.RegisterJSInclude(this, JS.ManagedScript.EktronJS);
        Ektron.Cms.API.JS.RegisterJSInclude(this, 
 Ektron.Cms.API.JS.ManagedScript.EktronJQueryClueTipJS);
        JS.RegisterJSInclude(this, JS.ManagedScript.EktronScrollToJS);
        JS.RegisterJSInclude(this, sitepath + "widgets/taxonomysummary/behavior.js", 
 "TaxonomySummaryWidgetBehaviorJS");

        if (TaxonomyId > 0)
        {
            TaxonomySelected = "";
            JS.RegisterJSBlock(this, "Ektron.PFWidgets.TaxonomySummary.webserviceURL = 
\"" + webserviceURL + "\"; 
 Ektron.PFWidgets.TaxonomySummary.setupAll();
 Ektron.PFWidgets.TaxonomySummary.SetTabs.init()
 ; ", "EktronPFWidgetsTSInit");
        }
        else
        {
            PropertySelected = "";
            JS.RegisterJSBlock(this, "Ektron.PFWidgets.TaxonomySummary.webserviceURL = 
  \"" + webserviceURL + "\"; 
 Ektron.PFWidgets.TaxonomySummary.setupAll(); ", "EktronPFWidgetsTSInit");
        }

        Css.RegisterCss(this, sitepath + "widgets/taxonomysummary/TSStyle.css",  
  "TSWidgetCSS");
        ViewSet.SetActiveView(Edit);
        //set taxonomy path
        Ektron.Cms.API.Content.Taxonomy _apiTaxonomy = new  
        Ektron.Cms.API.Content.Taxonomy();
        Ektron.Cms.TaxonomyRequest taxRequest = new Ektron.Cms.TaxonomyRequest();
        taxRequest.TaxonomyId = TaxonomyId;
        taxRequest.IncludeItems = false;
        taxRequest.TaxonomyLanguage = _apiTaxonomy.ContentLanguage;
        Ektron.Cms.TaxonomyData taxData = _apiTaxonomy.LoadTaxonomy(ref taxRequest);

        if (!(taxData == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(taxData.Path)))
        {
            taxonomypath.Text = taxData.Path;
            m_strTaxonomyPath = taxData.Path;
        }
        else
        {
            m_strTaxonomyPath = "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ViewSet.SetActiveView(View);
    }
}
#endregion

#region Button Events
protected void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewSet.SetActiveView(View);

}
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int taxID = Convert.ToInt32(taxonomyid.Text);
    TaxonomyId = taxID;
    taxFilter.Value = TaxonomyId.ToString();

    SetTaxonomySummary();
    _host.SaveWidgetDataMembers();
    ViewSet.SetActiveView(View);

}

#endregion

public EventArgs e { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: I request u Guys to give me some solution,i need it urgently please.....

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have the taxonomy id and want to display all the content within that taxonomy.  If that is not what you are after, then please clarify your question, and I'll try to help as best I can.

I find that the added baggage that comes along with a widget can sometimes make it hard to test for correct API and server control usage.  For that reason, I'd recommend starting off with a simple ASPX page.

```html
<ektron:ContentModelSource ID="contentModelSource" runat="server">
</ektron:ContentModelSource>

<ektron:ContentView ID="ContentView1" runat="server"  ModelSourceID="contentModelSource" EktronCustomTemplate="Ektron_ContentList_Template">
</ektron:ContentView>
```

Normally, the examples you'll find for the templated server controls show the declarative syntax for setting the filters, where you put them right into the ASPX markup - right inside the ContentModelSource control.  Something like:

```html
<TaxonomyFilters> 
    <ektron:ContentTaxonomyFilter Field="Id" Operator="EqualTo" Value="208" />
</TaxonomyFilters>
```

*(More examples [here](http://reference.ektron.com/developer/framework/ui/controls/TemplatedServerControls/Content/TaxonomyFilter.aspx) and [here](http://reference.ektron.com/developer/framework/ui/controls/TemplatedServerControls/AccessPoint/Taxonomy.aspx).)*

But for what it sounds like you want to accomplish, you need to define the filters via code.  This code does just that:

```cs
protected long TaxonomyId
{
    get
    {
        long id;
        long.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id);
        return id;
    }
}

protected bool IsRecursive
{
    get
    {
        bool recursive;
        bool.TryParse(Request.QueryString["recursive"], out recursive);
        return recursive;
    }
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TaxonomyId > 0)
    {
        if (IsRecursive)
        {
            var tm = new TaxonomyManager();
            var td = tm.GetItem(TaxonomyId);
            if (td != null)
            {
                var pathFilter = new ContentTaxonomyFilter();
                pathFilter.Field = ContentTaxonomyProperty.Path;
                pathFilter.Operator = CriteriaFilterOperator.StartsWith;
                pathFilter.Value = td.Path;

                contentModelSource.TaxonomyFilters.Add(pathFilter);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var filter = new ContentTaxonomyFilter();
            filter.Field = ContentTaxonomyProperty.Id;
            filter.Value = TaxonomyId.ToString();
            filter.Operator = CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo;

            contentModelSource.TaxonomyFilters.Add(filter);                
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of things to note:

- The TaxonomyId is a property.  I did this so that there would be an easy point of comparison between this simple ASPX page and a custom widget where your property would be decorated with the `WidgetDataMember` attribute.
- The code is in the Page_Init event handler.  That is important.  Page_Load is too late in the page's lifecycle.  I assume this would also be true in the context of a widget.
- My code for when `IsRecursive == true` is not necessarily optimized.  You could get reasonable performance by [turning on caching in the FrameworkAPI](http://www.ektron.com/Blogs/eGandalf/Cache-Me-If-You-Can/), but the idea of calling the api to get the taxonomyData and then using that to set the filter for the content seems a little off.  Ideally, the ContentTaxonomyFilter would have a "Recursive" property.